# Using structured references in excel table for subranges

Tags: excel

I have a table wherein I use formulas that are currently non-structured, because I am resizing the table and populating afterwards my formulas will mess up. For that reason I want to use structured references to avoid it.

Example:
[image]

In the picture below I want to change the address `$V$10:V15` to something akin to `[Index (fund)]:[@[Index (fund)]]`, such that it still only takes the range from the beginning of the table to the current row and not the whole range, like in the picture.

Comment: I don't know how much calculation is done throughout the rest of the table but you could 1: Transpose the table, i.e. switch rows and column. Or 2: Use the Offset Command (which is still kinda non-structured). 3: Create a helper column with the calculations needed. Tables are useless when you want to compute stuff on other rows.

Comment: I made the following test. Enter an = sign in a cell outside a table. Then select the first cell in any column. The test cell will show the cell reference of that cell. As you increase the selection, the test cell will show a larger range, expressed in conventional range referencing syntax. When you reach the bottom of the column the test cell will show the selection in structured syntax. Therefore I believe that structured syntax can't be used to address part of a column.

Comment: Try `=MIN(Table1[[#Headers],[Index (fund)]]:[@[Index (fund)]])`

Comment: You can use INDEX to define part of a table column, like 'INDEX(Table1[Test)],1)' and you might draw totals like you describe with a construct like '=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(Table1[Test],1,1),,, 2,1))' but the 2 in this formula would have to be generated using a reference to the sheet row, adjusted for the first row of the table. I didn't find a function to return the table row number. My temptation is to say that your project would be better off in a normal spreadsheet with dynamic named ranges. If you insist on using a table, stick with normal cell referencing.

Answer (score 1):

One method, using structured references, is to use the `INDEX` function to refer to the first row. So, to do a running total of a **Value** column, you could use:

```
=SUM(INDEX([Value],1,1):[@Value])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While this solution is not a structured references per say it solves my problem.

I made a helper column to reference the range for each cell, looking like this

[image]

Using the code `="$V10:V"&ROW([@[Index (fund)]])` and filling down. Now for the actual calculation I want I simply use the function `=INDIRECT` for the corresponding row to reference the string as the range, i.e. `=MIN([@[Index (fund)]]/MAX(INDIRECT([@[Ref draw PF]]))-1,0)` instead of the original formula `=MIN([@[Index (fund)]]/MAX($V$10:V15)-1,0)`